# Can I access codeclimate.com from a command line interface?

Tags: command-line-interface

I get very confused when using Code Climate because I find their GUI extremely poorly thought out and implemented. Wondering if there is a way to work with codeclimate.com from the command line (similar to how I work with github.com without having to use the browser).

Answer (score 2):

They have [an official CLI package](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate) which requires [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Installation instructions and documentation are on the package's github page.